# Can I disable a gesture?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a datagrid and this gestures?

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding DatagridMouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataGridMouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGrid, Path=SelectedItems, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

I know that in a button, I can the property IsEnabled, but in the gestures in the data grid I don't have this property.

How can I disable the command of a gesture in the datagrid?

Comment: Command should also have `CanExecute`. Can you not control it from there?

Comment: dkozl is right, I agree with him. You should put your enable/disable logic in the CanExecute method/delegate of your command. In this way the related InputBindings are enabled/disabled.